# @3x image, Iphone 8 Plus, Iphone X

Tags: ios, xcode

Let's assume, I have selected 'View as: iPhone 8 Plus' on Main.storyboard in Xcode. We know these details:

```
Iphone X: 375 x 812 points (@3x) 1125x2436 pixels
Iphone 8 Plus: 414 x 736 points (@3x) 1242 × 2208 pixels
Iphone 8: 375 x 667 points (@2x) 750x1334 pixel
```

Let's assume I would like to put an UIImageView (top bar, header bar image) like below:

[image: Brown rectangle is an image(header bar)]

Remember, I have selected 'View as: iPhone 8 Plus'. So width of the image must be 414 points. And let's assume height of the image is 100 points. So image size must be 1242 x 300 pixels. (because 414points*3=1242px, 100points*3=300px)

so,

```
@3xBackground.png must be 1242 x 300 pixels.
    @2xBackground.png must be 828x200, right? **(this is question 1)**
    @1xBackground.png must be 414x100, right? **(this is question 2)**
```

What about IPhone X? Iphone X also uses @3xBackground.png image, right? **(this is question3)**

I see this image so sharp at iphone 8 plus. Because I create this image regarding to the iPhone 9 plus. But i can't see this image so sharp in iPhone x. Because width of iPhone X is 375points(1125 pixels) but my image width is 414 points(1242 pixels) Am i right? iphone x and iphone 8 plus use same image: @3xBackground.png. Device tries to put 1242pixel image in to 1125 px place. So how does this picture look so sharp?

Does Iphone X reduce height of the image when it puts 1242 pixel image in to 1125 px place ? **(This is question 4)** If reply yes. So it should be fine.